# How can I add asc/desc sorting by every column to my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, redux, react-redux

I created github-search-app with react + redux . (+thunk)

So here is the code of my app on GitHub (it is really a very, very simple app).

https://github.com/elminsterrr/react-js-github-search-app

[image]

After each search, the search result is saved to redux store. Now I want to use that locally saved data and manipulate them. So I want to add to my project this features:

1. Pagination
2. Ability to control number of rows rendered (5/10/15/20)
3. Asc/desc sorting by every column (after clicking on column name)

1 and 2 are ok, but this (***"Asc/desc sorting by every column"***) looks hard to me. I'm stuck.

Please write how you would approach that problem and maybe it will be enough to get me going...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you building the table component instead of using the react-table component from npm?
[Example](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table)

Otherwise you need to order items in the state by dispatching an action that contains the column name so you could identify the prop to sort your data through.

Comment: thx, I didn't know that such thing exists. I will try to add it to my project!